# Running PySpark using Cronjob (crontab)

Tags: python, pyspark, cron

First, I assume that we have `SPARK_HOME` set up, in my case it's at `~/Desktop/spark-2.0.0`. Basically, I want to run my PySpark script using Cronjob (e.g. `crontab -e`). My question is how to add environment path to make Spark script works with Cronjob. Here is my sample script, `example.py`

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

# Configure the environment
if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '~/Desktop/spark-2.0.0'

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('example').setMaster('local[8]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ls = range(100)
    ls_rdd = sc.parallelize(ls, numSlices=10)
    ls_out = ls_rdd.map(lambda x: x+1).collect()

    f = open('test.txt', 'w')
    for item in ls_out:
        f.write("%s\n" % item) # save list to test.txt
```

My bash script in `run_example.sh` is as follows

```
rm test.txt

~/Desktop/spark-2.0.0/bin/spark-submit \
  --master local[8] \
  --driver-memory 4g \
  --executor-memory 4g \
  example.py
```

Here, I want to run `run_example.sh` every minutes using `crontab`. However, I don't know how to custom path when I run `crontab -e`. So far, I only see this [Gitbook link](https://zedar.gitbooks.io/spark-hadoop-notes/content/spark_job_running_in_cron.html). I have something like this in my Cronjob editor that doesn't run my code yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

# add path to cron (this line is the one I don't know)
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/anaconda/bin

# run script every minutes
* * * * * source run_example.sh
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is , add following line in your .bashrc file in home location.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

then you can have following entry in crontab

```
* * * * * source ~/.bashrc;sh run_example.sh
```

This line will execute your .bashrc file first, which will set the PATH value, then it will execute run_example.sh

Alternatively, you can set the PATH in run_example.sh only,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/anaconda/bin
rm test.txt

~/Desktop/spark-2.0.0/bin/spark-submit \
  --master local[8] \
  --driver-memory 4g \
  --executor-memory 4g \
  example.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sarwesh! Basically, `source ~/.bashrc` is what I'm looking for. I didn't know before that we can run multiple bash shell in one line!